# Complexity of solving multiple problems of the same complexity?

Tags: complexity-theory

If I am given two languages $A$ and $B$ which are in NP, then we know that there exists a NDTM that can decide $A$ in polynomial time, and there exists another NDTM that can decide $B$ in polynomial time. Can I decide $A$ and $B$ in polynomial time using a NDTM by simply using a NDTM to check for belonging in $A$ then use another NDTM to check for belonging in $B$ and if both accept then it belongs to both $A$ and $B$?

Comment: What do you mean by "deciding $A$ and $B$"? Are you considering $A \cap B$?

Comment: Yea. I suppose $A \cap B$ would be the same thing that I am asking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can test whether $A \cap B$ is in $\textsf{NP}$ by testing $A$ and $B$ separately. Actually, you have proven that the class $\textsf{NP}$ is closed under intersection. See [this lecture note (Exercise 1)](http://people.cs.aau.dk/~srba/courses/tutorials-CC-10/t13-sol.pdf) for details and other cases.

Comment: In a very similar way you can prove that $\mathsf{NP}$ is closed under union. More generally, it is closed under any monotone Boolean function (for example, majority of $2k+1$ different languages).